# Tweak number of "recent documents" in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, start-menu

Is there a way to change the number of "recently opened documents" in the Start menu of Windows XP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The registry key

```
KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\MaxRecentDocs
```

controls the number of documents in the Recent Documents folder.

Here's a reg file from **[Kelly's Korner](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm)** (210/R), changing the value to 25

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"MaxRecentDocs"=dword:00000019
```

copy/paste into notepad, save as `maxrecent25.reg` and import.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a bit more involved than what I was hoping for, but that's the way it is, I guess.